# powershell script to return all forwarding rules in org

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to pull all forwarding rules for an exchange online environment, and output them to a csv. this sounds simple, but I have an additional caveat. there are 23,000 mailboxes in the org.

I was able to write the script I needed, it outputted the data, but it timed out.
then I was able to break out only certain mailboxes that were critical (11,000) but I was still timing out in powershell.

so finally, I found an article that detailed breaking up a script into blocks of 1,000, and running numerous sessions. and runs! it runs without timing out.
but it doesn't output to the csv anymore.
since my script has gone through several iterations, I'm pretty sure that my problem is the way I'm storing, or outputting the array, but for all my staring at this, I cant figure it out. short of asking the doc for a prescription of Adderall, I figured id ask here. below is the offending script.

the aliaslist.csv that it mentions is just a csv with a list of aliases for 11,000 mailboxes. if you would like to run your own tests, you can adjust $pagesize down and paste a few mailboxes into a csv called aliaslist, stored in c:\temp

```
    Function New-O365ExchangeSession()

{

param( 

[parameter(mandatory=$true)]

$365master)

#close any old remote session

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession -Confirm:$false

#start a new office 365 remote session

$365session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $365master -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

$office365 = Import-PSSession $365session

}



#set input variables
$path = "C:\temp"
$InputFile = aliaslist.csv"
$UserEmail = "admin@domain.com"

#set variables for csv usage
$Offset = 0;
$PageSize = 1000;
$MbxMax = (Import-Csv "$path/$InputFile").count



#Loop in the list and retrieve the device’s information

$file = “c:\temp\office365-$((get-date).tostring(“yyyy-MM-dd”)).csv”

$365master = get-credential $UserEmail

New-O365ExchangeSession $365master 
# call the office365 remote connection function


do{
$mbxlist=@(import-csv "$path/$InputFile"|select-object -skip $Offset -First $PageSize)

"Process entry $($Offset) to $($Offset+$PageSize)"

#end csv input count reference


ForEach($mbx in $MbxList)

    {
    #Write to Host
    "start Processing $($mbx.alias)"
    #end Write to host, 





        #Check rules
        $rules = Get-InboxRule -mailbox $_.alias | ? {$_.RedirectTo -ne $null -or $_.ForwardTo -ne $null -or $_.ForwardAsAttachmentTo -ne $null}
        If ($rules -ne $null)
        {
            $rules | % {

                #check for forwardAsAttachments
                If ($_.ForwardAsAttachmentTo -ne $null)
                {
                    $obj = New-Object system.object
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "NetID" -Value $_.alias -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardType" -Value "Forward As Attachment Rule" -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardAddress" -Value $_.forwardAsAttachmentTo -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Enabled" -Value $_.Enabled -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Description" -Value $f -MemberType NoteProperty

                        If (Test-Path $file)
                       {
                             $mbx.alias + ”,” + ($obj | ConvertTo-Csv)[2] | Out-File $file –Append
                          }
                         Else
                       {
                      $obj | Export-Csv $file -Encoding ASCII -notypeinformation
                     }
                }
                $obj = $null


                #check for redirects
                If ($_.redirectto -ne $null)
                {
                    $obj = New-Object system.object
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "NetID" -Value $_.alias -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardType" -Value "Redirct Rule" -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardAddress" -Value $_.redirectto -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Enabled" -Value $_.Enabled -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Description" -Value $c -MemberType NoteProperty

                        If (Test-Path $file)

                       {
                             $mbx.alias + ”,” + ($obj | ConvertTo-Csv)[2] | Out-File $file –Append
                          }
                         Else
                       {
                      $obj | Export-Csv $file -Encoding ASCII -notypeinformation
                     }
                }   
                $obj = $null


            #check for forwards
                If ($_.ForwardTo -ne $null)
                {
                    $obj = New-Object system.object
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "NetID" -Value $_.alias -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardType" -Value "Forward Rule" -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "ForwardAddress" -Value $_.forwardto -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Enabled" -Value $_.Enabled -MemberType NoteProperty
                    $obj | Add-Member -name "Description" -Value $f -MemberType NoteProperty    
                        If (Test-Path $file)
                       {
                             ($obj | ConvertTo-Csv)[2] | Out-File $file –Append
                          }
                         Else
                       {
                      $obj | Export-Csv $file -Encoding ASCII -notypeinformation
                     }
                }   
                $obj = $null
            }       
        }
         }






#increment the start point for the next chunk
$Offset+=$PageSize


#Call the office365 remote session function to close the current one and open a new session

New-O365ExchangeSession $365master

} while($Offset -lt $MbxMax)
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the OperationTimeout? The default is 3 minutes. This is probably the timeout that kills your script.

Comment: I havnt, its for office 365, I'm not sure you are allowed to change the timeout in o365 are you?

Comment: It is a PSSession setting, could be worth a try tough.

Comment: ok, so I wasn't able to find any timeout adjust solutions when I was first researching, but then you posted it, so I thought I might have missed it.
I searched again, and found this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7de3d593-27a8-441a-9d03-6aed170f974f/disable-timeout-on-newpssession?forum=winserverpowershell and this: http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Powershell_change_the_wmi_timeout_value both seem to imply that Its not practical for my situation.

Comment: but then I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855822/powershell-command-timeout and it mentions doing background runspaces.

between me and you, id much rather fix my array issue than rewrite the whole thing again to use background runspaces.

Comment: ok, so with the code above, there is an output but its all wonky.
the first line in the csv is missing the alias, then each subsequent line is a copy of that line, except it has an alias, but there seems to be an empty value inserted afterwards witch pushes the other columns out by 1

Comment: ahah!
so I tore it all down today and started from scratch, and I found out my issue is occurring in the script that I based mine off.
if you run the final script here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashour/2014/04/30/large-tenant-and-powershell-io-timeout/ the same issue occurs,
that being all the lines of data are effed except one, but they all seem to contain data.

so I guess I need to start by figuring out how to get this guys code working, then I can adapt it for my needs.
I don't know whay I assumed it would work.