# Exit from a command if it takes too much time in powershell

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

```
$uri="http:\\www.SomeUrl.com"
Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing}
```

In above powershell script, how can I exit from Invoke-WebRequest if it takes time more than 10 secs, and return a error code if possible.

Comment: For cmdlets that do not have already a `-Timeout` parameter, see: [Powershell command timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855822/powershell-command-timeout)

Comment: In general, you can set a timeout on jobs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176487/adding-a-timeout-to-batch-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Timeout parameter to the Invoke-WebRequest command,

```
$uri="http://www.SomeUrl.com"
Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -Timeout 10}
```

You can cover it with try / catch block to get the error message.

```
try {
    $uri="http://www.SomeUrl.com"
    Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -Timeout 10 -ErrorAction Stop}
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Timeout occured. Exception: $_"
}
```

You can also use `-Headers @{"Cache-Control"="no-cache"}` with `Invoke-WebRequest` which will not cache the pages you are visiting.

Comment: try {
    $uri="http:\\www.google.com"
    $time=Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -Timeout 1 -ErrorAction Stop}
 Write-Host "Total Seconds: "$time.TotalSeconds
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Timeout occured. Exception: $_"
}


Hi, I tried the above thing, but the result I got is as below

output:

Total Seconds:  4.1600271

Comment: Since it has exceeded 1 second, it should through error right.

Comment: When you make a call, multiple times, the data Is already cached. Try that with another site that might take longer to download

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked with different url. But , is there any way to clear the cache and continue with same url.

Comment: `-Headers @{"Cache-Control"="no-cache"}` ... you can add this to your Invoke-WebRequest